# Run a command every 5 minutes and stop it at the end of that time

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have to run NodeJS application which has to run uninterruptedly, but I need to stop it and restart it every 10 minutes.
I'm Working on a dedicated Ubuntu 18.04 machine.
I have read something about cron but I don't know well how it works. Does it stop the command that was run with it?

Comment: You can manage node.js apps with https://github.com/foreverjs/forever. Maybe use with cron and a shell script. Just an idea.

Comment: This may be a good topic for [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Once you decide what you need then you can ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to run the application, and set up a cron job to restart it in forever every five minutes. As a bonus, forever will also restart it for you if it fails in between cron job executions.

Comment: I understand what you're telling me, you could kindly give an example

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, the cron doesn't stop the command that had run before, but you could add the logic to do that check in your application.

Here you can find an article that shows some solutions to [prevent duplicate cron job executions](https://bencane.com/2015/09/22/preventing-duplicate-cron-job-executions/).